# How to filter files with specific permissions or attributes while running ls?

Tags: linux, find, ls

For example, if I only want the files that have the permission `g+s` while running `ls`, how could I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ls` doesn't provide this – it's typically used for just tweaking display options. What you can do instead involves using [**`find`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Mode-Bits). For example:

```
find . -perm -g+s
```

To mimic `ls`'s behavior of only listing files in the current directors, use the `-maxdepth 1` option.

The possible combinations are endless. Refer to the `find` help linked above for more examples and the syntax differences in using `-` or `/` before the *mode*, also with respect to `/` being a GNU-only extension and `+` being used in BSD-style `find`.